# Apache tomcat 7 No error with localhost page, But when run project: show HTTP Status 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, localhost, http-status-code-404

I know there are many questions about Apache tomcat 404 error: but I think mine is different.

- I am using windows 7 64 bit
- unzipped **eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64** to C:\
- unzipped **apache-tomcat-7.0.37-windows-x64**
- changed port server.xml to 3030 instead of 8080
- continue with [this steps](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html) **"Quick Start"** from point (2)
- **I didn't forget:**
- copying ROOT folder
- R-click tomcat node in eclipse Servers tab -> properties -> Switch location
- Double click tomcat node in Project explorer and check **use tomcat instillation (takes control of tomcat installation)**

The page:`http://localhost:3030/` works fine. It shows the message **If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!**

**But** when I tried simple project (I followed [basic tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oX2rw5pAdxw&list=PLE0F6C1917A427E96&index=2)) and use **Run as** -> **Run on Server** the page of error 404 is shown. When back to `http://localhost:3030/` it shows no error.

- No error with `http://localhost:3030/`
- Error when running a project!

> HTTP Status 404 - /SimpleProject/
>
> ---
>
> type Status report
>
> message /SimpleProject/
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> ---
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.37

Comment: When running your application on tomcat, you can see if there are any problem when installing the application in the log/console. Have you checked that? If there aren't any, you could try to access files inside of the webapp like "/SimpleProject/index.jsp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am The author of this question, and I solved it. I will provide the solution so that others can get help from it.

As I followed this [installation steps](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html) carefully, then the installation is correct.

The only problem that caused the error is in the **web.xml**:
- When create a new "Dynamic Web Project" (As my case)
- Take care of this file: **WebContent -> WEB-INF -> web.xml**
- The `<welcome-file>  </welcome-file>` tags must refer to exist files to display in the browser.
- If there are some default tags delete them.
- when you create for example a new HTML file named **index.html**, then make sure that the **web.xml** file refers to it. `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>`

---

**Digression** (irrelevant to the solution above)
I am actually working on NetBeans extensively doing simple Java Standard Edition projects. I rarely encountered problems with NetBeans, and when they occur I can solve them easily either myself or by searching for information about the problem.

When I began learning the Java Entrprise Edition, and see tutorial on NetBeans, I started my first project from the **first** day.

But I found most of the tutorials use Eclipse and that was the reason why I installed it.

When I moved to Eclipse. I encountered many problems, and each problem take many hours to  search and solve. that takes **three** days before starting one project.

I am wondering why people prefer Eclipse over NetBeans. I think there is some reason. (^_^)